# How do I remove a specific line from a text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text

I don't know what should I do in order the remove the book from the file.

My code takes input from the user to determine which book they want to delete from the list. Then I open the text file and read it.

I researched using `.strip()` but seems like it is not working and I am not familiar with the function of `.strip()`

```
def delete_book():
    book_to_delete = input('Please input the name of the book that will be removed from the library: ')
    with open("listOfBook.txt", "r") as list_of_books:
        books = list_of_books.readlines()
    with open('listOfBook.txt', 'w') as list_of_books:
        for book in books:
            if book.strip('\n') != book_to_delete:
                list_of_books.write(book)
                print(book_to_delete, 'had been removed from the library data base')
                input('Please press enter to go back to staff menu')
```

This is my text file (`listOfBook.txt`):

```
The Great Gatsby
To Kill a Mockingbird
Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone
1984
```

Comment: Your code is mostly correct **as long as there is no other whitespace on the lines**. So if your lines are like `"The Great Gatsby      \n"` then `.strip"\n")` produces `"The Great Gatsby      "`, which won't be equal to `"The Great Gatsby"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct insofar that it'll correctly remove the `\n` characters from your lines.

You also have an indentation issue with telling the user that the book has been removed, but that could be an issue with how you posted the code in your question here. It doesn't affect how your code tests each line.

However, removing the `\n` characters from each `book` value doesn't mean that the string read from the file will match the string the user typed:

- Your lines could have extra whitespace. That's harder to see when you open your book file in a text editor, but you can test this by using a little bit more Python code.

  Try using either the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) or the [`ascii()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii) to print the line, which will make them look as if they are Python string literals. If you are only using English text, the difference between `ascii` and `repr()` doesn't really matter; what's important is that you get to see the string value in a way that makes it easier to spot things like spaces.

  Just add a `print("The value of book is:", ascii(book))` and perhaps `print("The value of book_to_delete is:", ascii(book_to_delete))` to your loop:

  ```
  with open('listOfBook.txt', 'w') as list_of_books:
      for book in books:
          print("The value of book is:", ascii(book))
          print("The value of book_to_delete is:", ascii(book_to_delete))
          if book.strip('\n') != book_to_delete:
  ```

  You could remove the `"\n"` argument from `str.strip()` and remove **all** whitespace characters from start and end to solve this:

  ```
  if book.strip() != book_to_delete.strip():
  ```

  You can play with the function in a Python interactive session:

  ```
  >>> book = "The Great Gatsby   \n"
  >>> book
  'The Great Gatsby   \n'
  >>> print(book.strip("\n"))
  The Great Gatsby
  >>> print(ascii(book.strip("\n")))
  'The Great Gatsby   '
  >>> print(ascii(book.strip()))
  'The Great Gatsby'
  ```

  Notice how `print(book.strip("\n"))` doesn't really show you that there are extra spaces there, but `print(ascii(book.strip("\n")))` shows, by the location of the `'...'` quoting, that the string is longer. Finally, using `str.strip()` with no arguments removed those extra spaces.

  Also, note that the user could also be adding extra spaces, do remove those too.
- The user could be using a different mix of uppercase and lowercase characters. You could use the [`str.casefold()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold)` on both values to make sure that differences in casing are ignored:

  ```
  if book.strip().casefold() != book_to_delete.casefold():
  ```

Your code, as posted, has an indentation issue. The lines

```
print(book_to_delete, 'had been removed from the library data base')
input('Please press enter to go back to staff menu')
```

are currently indented to fall under the `if book.strip('\n') != book_to_delete:` test block, so they are executed *each time a `book` value from your file is tested and found to be a different book*.

You want to remove enough indentation so that only is indented once past the level of `def delete_book():`, so still part of the function, but not part of any other block:

```
def delete_book():
    book_to_delete = input('Please input the name of the book that will be removed from the library: ')
    with open("listOfBook.txt", "r") as list_of_books:
        books = list_of_books.readlines()
    with open('listOfBook.txt', 'w') as list_of_books:
        for book in books:
            if book.strip() != book_to_delete.strip():
                list_of_books.write(book)
    print(book_to_delete, 'had been removed from the library data base')
    input('Please press enter to go back to staff menu')
```

That way it is only executed after you have written all lines that don't match `book_to_delete` to the file, and the file has been closed. Note that in the above example, I also changed `.strip("\n")` into `.strip()` and added an extra `strip()` call to the user input too..

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code ever so slightly and hopefully will be able to explain some issues you were having (some might have been just formatting of the question)

```py
def delete_book():
    book_to_delete = input('Please input the name of the book that will be removed from the library: ')
    with open("listOfBook.txt", "r") as list_of_books:
        books = list_of_books.readlines()
    with open('listOfBook.txt', 'w') as list_of_books:
        for book in books:
            if book.strip('\n').strip() != book_to_delete:  # Code Changes
                list_of_books.write(book)
            else:                                           # Code Changes
                print(book_to_delete, 'had been removed from the library data base')
    input('Please press enter to go back to staff menu')
```

First of all I have added a second `.strip()` to the check on line 7. This will remove any leading or trailing white space (which will result in a no match)

Additionally I have restructured some of the logic with the reporting of 'When a book is deleted'

Hopefully this does as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
book_to_delete = input('Please input the name of the book that will be removed from 
the library: ')
with open("listOfBook.txt", "r") as list_of_books:
books = [line.strip() for line in list_of_books]

found_book = False
for i in range(len(books)):
  if books[i] == book_to_delete:
    found_book = True
    break

if found_book == False:
  print("Book not found in the list")
else:
  books.remove(book_to_delete)
  open('listOfBook.txt', 'w').close()

  with open('listOfBook.txt', 'w') as list_of_books:
    for bookTitle in books:
        list_of_books.write('%s\n' % bookTitle)
```

Comment: I hope it makes sense, please ask for any clarity